# What is the distinction between πολύσπλαγχνός and οἰκτίρμων in James 5:11?

Tags: hebrew, greek, james, hapax-legomenon

In the letter of James, 5:11, the author writes:

> τὸ τέλος Κυρίου εἴδετε, ὅτι πολύσπλαγχνός ἐστιν ὁ Κύριος καὶ οἰκτίρμων

English translations frequently seem to render the two adjectives πολύσπλαγχνός and οἰκτίρμων as, respectively,

- full of compassion / compassionate / merciful / full of tenderness / very pitiful / full of pity
- merciful / pitiful / of tender mercy

The general sense is clear to me (I think!) but I am curious about whether there is a meaningful distinction between them, or if they are two near-synonyms that are just being put together for emphasis.

The passage stood out to me because "compassionate and merciful" is a well-known description of God in Islam, and the two adjectives there are understood to have related but distinct meanings. In Arabic, they come from the same r-h-m root, whereas the two Greek words here don't seem to have a common root. So I was wondering whether there might be a similar pair of r-h-m words in Hebrew which the Greek adjectives are "translating".

So my question is:

- What detailed explanation can be given for the related meanings of these two words?
- Does their combination reflect any similar pairing in Hebrew?

(The word πολύσπλαγχνός only occurs once in the NT, so I've tagged this question with *hapax legomenon* even though the related σπλάγχνα pops up more often.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question as posed by OP -- concerning aspects of the "πολύσπλαγχνος + οἰκτίρμων" pair in [James 5:11](http://goo.gl/z4BDKV) -- has all the seeds of its own answer. First, the relevant bit of text:

> NA28 ... **πολύσπλαγχνός** ἐστιν ὁ κύριος καὶ **οἰκτίρμων**.
>   NRSV ... the Lord is **compassionate** and **merciful**.

I'll take the interrelated sub-questions in a slightly different order.

#### (1) Does their combination reflect any similar pairing in Hebrew?

Yes, it does. In [Exodus 34:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=exodus%2034%3A6&version=RSV;WLC) there is the famous statement:

> MT: יְהוָה יְהוָה אֵל **רַחוּם וְחַנּוּן** אֶרֶךְ אַפַּיִם וְרַב־חֶסֶד וֶאֱמֶת
>   Heb: *yhwh yhwh, ʾēl **raḥûm wĕḥannûn**, ʾerek ʾappayim, wĕrab-ḥesed weʾĕmet*
>   Trans: The LORD the LORD, a God **merciful and gracious**, slow to anger, and abounding in steadfast love and faithfulness

In [the LXX](http://www.katapi.org.uk/katapiNSBunix/Lxx/LxxByBC.php?GB=2&GC=34) the relevant pair looks like this:

> LXX: ... οἰκτίρμων καὶ ἐλεήμων ...

*That* pairing ("compassionate and merciful") is applied to God 10x in the LXX with a reflex in the Hebrew text (MT): Exod. 34:6; 2 Chr. 30:9; Neh. 9:17, 31; Ps. 86[85]:15; 102:8; 111[110]:4;* 145[144]:8; Joel 2:13; and Jon. 4:2. It also occurs Ecclesiasticus 2:11, where this "confession" appears in full. Of the total 12 occurrences, 5x οἰκτίρμων comes first, and 7x ἐλεήμων comes first.
<sub>* + Ps 112[111]:4, used of the one who fears the LORD, in parallel to 111[110]:4. Numbers in square brackets are LXX Psalm numbers.</sub>

As noted by OP, the word in the James 5:11 pair is the unique (in the LXX and NT) πολύσπλαγχνός rather than the typical member from the LXX, ἐλεήμων.

According to Moulton and Milligan's entry for πολύσπλαγχνός<sup>1</sup> it is the equivalent of πολυέλεος in the LXX,<sup>2</sup> "very merciful" (πολυ "much" + έλεος "mercy"), so closely related to ἐλεήμων.

#### (2) What detailed explanation can be given for the related meanings of these two words?

Any OP who can pose a question so thoughtfully ought to be able to go a good distance on this already. `;)` But here are some quick thoughts based partly on observation of the text (where it starts, after all), and partly from quick checks in Jenni & Westermann (eds), *[Theological Lexicon of the Old Testament](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1565631331)* [*TLOT*], and the venerable Kittel & Friedrich (eds), *[Theological Dictionary of the New Tesatment](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=D6aTnQEACAAJ)* [*TDNT*].

The theological nuance of the **Hebrew** pair, *raḥûm wĕḥannûn*, can be teased apart this way:

- **raḥûm** carries the sense of pardon or sparing, i.e. mercy where wrath might have been present; while
- **ḥannûn** is the king's gracious and beneficent presence with his people for good.

Stoebe's article (רחם, *TLOT*, 3.1227; he also did the חנן article) emphasizes the frequency with which these occur together as a liturgical saying. I can only find two occurrences each where they appear without the other (*raḥûm* "alone": Deut 4:31; Ps 78:38; and *ḥannûn* "alone", Exod 22:27[v. 26 in Heb], but Ps 116:5 includes *raḥēm*).

In **Greek**. the pairing works this way (with typical Hebrew counterpart):

- **ἐλεήμων** (*ḥannûn*) is merciful compassion; while
- **οἰκτίρμων** (*raḥûm*) is sympathy, pity, involving compassionate intervention.

If there is some sense of confusion at this point, that is probably a good thing. The history of the use of these terms is deeply intertwined, with the σπλαγχν- group -- which in earlier Greek usage simply had its literal sense (normally) of "innards" before being used as a translation equivalent for *raḥûm* in the LXX (with its own literal meaning of "womb") -- beginning to displace οἰκτίρμων in some measure (cf. Koester, *TDNT*, 7.550-553). Within that group is James 5:11's πολύσπλαγχνος.<sup>3</sup> These terms have their own development in Greek, apart from the related Hebrew vocabulary, and it is ἐλεήμων that is "displaced", rather than οἰκτίρμων.

And so, having said all that...

#### (3) Is there a meaningful distinction between them?

Probably not. One can see more meaningful distinctions between the underlying Hebrew terms, but even in the Tanakh they tend to appear as a set-pair. By the time you get to the inter-related use of the terms in Greek, with their dependence on the LXX and in some sense a "liturgical" use, then Bultmann's contention (*TDNT*, 5.161) that they form a sort of *hendiadys* makes very good sense, emphatically expressive of "heartfelt compassion".<sup>4</sup>

---

*Notes*

1. James Hope Moulton & George Milligan, *[The vocabulary of the Greek Testament illustrated from the papyri and other non-literary sources](https://archive.org/details/vocabularyofgree00mouluoft)* (Hodder & Stoughton, 1914-1929), [p. 527](https://archive.org/stream/vocabularyofgree00mouluoft#page/527/mode/1up):
        "very pitiful." This word, confined in the NT to Jas 5 11, is said to be found elsewhere
        only in Hermas *Mand.* iv.3.5, *Sim.* v.7.4. It is the equivalent of the LXX πολυέλεος
        (Ps 102:8). See *s.v.* **[σπλάγχνον](https://archive.org/stream/vocabularyofgree00mouluoft#page/584/mode/1up)**.
   Before anyone jumps on my citation of this old reference work, please read [Larry Hurtado's panegyric](https://larryhurtado.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/nt-vocabulary-in-historical-context/). Thank you.
2. Used 11x - Exod. 34:6; Num. 14:18; Neh. 9:17; 3 Ma. 6:9; Ps. 85:5, 15; 102:8; 144:8; Odes 12:7; Joel 2:13; Jon. 4:2 (all **LXX** references).
3. There are about a dozen (maybe a few more) uses in the post-apostolic and later literature (e.g., Shepherd of Hermas, Clement of Alexandria, in the Acts of Thomas).
4. The few modern commentaries I've consulted aren't especially interested in the phrase *per se*. See, however, J.H. Ropes, *[A critical and exegetical commentary on the Epistle of St. James](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL7184620M/A_critical_and_exegetical_commentary_on_the_Epistle_of_St._James.)* (T & T Clark, 1916), [pp. 299-300](https://archive.org/stream/criticalexegetic00ropeuoft#page/299/mode/1up) for some useful comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for this tremendously interesting and helpful answer!

Comment: Glad it was a help. I also got a bit muddled just before heading **(3)**. Have a look at the revision -- not that it will be tremedously clear. In mitigation ;) there is quite a complex interrelated development of the terms. If this is of interest, it would certainly be worthwhile gathering the data yourself to see how it all fits together. This is a start, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Very thoughtful answer ... the only thing I would add is that the above answer seems a little deficient in "teasing" the terms apart in the following way:

"The theological nuance of the Hebrew pair, raḥûm wĕḥannûn, can be teased apart this way:
   raḥûm carries the sense of pardon or sparing, i.e. mercy where wrath might have been 
   present; while ḥannûn is the king's gracious and beneficent presence with his people for 
   good."

What really should be noted about raḥûm is its highly emotional nature--i.e., it is derived from the word rhm meaning a mother's womb, and often indicates a profound inner emotional movement--thus, indicating that Yahweh in Scripture is deeply affected by the suffering and need of His people--See Psalm 103.